# How to Get All Items from Room Database?

Tags: android, android-room, android-jetpack

How to get all items from room database? Want to get all items from room database.

```
@Dao
interface ItemDao {
    @Query("SELECT * from items ORDER BY name ASC")
    fun getAllItems(): Flow<List<Item>>
}
```

```
@Composable
fun MyUi() {
    LaunchedEffect("lorem") {
        Log.d("myTag", db.getAllItems().toString())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I listen data list from room database normally

```
getAllItems().distinctUntilChanged().collectLatest { list -> // Log to see data list }
```

You can base on this website of android developer : https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow